# searching Tags (TLV) with C function

Tags: c, hex, apdu, contactless-smartcard, tlv

I' m working on Mastercard Paypass transactions, I Have sent a READ RECORD command and got the result:

```
70 81 AB 57 11 54 13 33 00 89 60 10 83 D2 51 22 
20 01 23 40 91 72 5A 08 54 13 33 00 89 60 10 83 
5F 24 03 25 12 31 5F 25 03 04 01 01 5F 28 02 00 
56 5F 34 01 01 8C 21 9F 02 06 9F 03 06 9F 1A 02 
95 05 5F 2A 02 9A 03 9C 01 9F 37 04 9F 35 01 9F 
45 02 9F 4C 08 9F 34 03 8D 0C 91 0A 8A 02 95 05 
9F 37 04 9F 4C 08 8E 0E 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
42 03 5E 03 1F 03 9F 07 02 FF 00 9F 08 02 00 02 
9F 0D 05 00 00 00 00 00 9F 0E 05 00 08 00 60 00 
9F 0F 05 00 00 00 00 00 9F 42 02 09 78 9F 4A 01 
82 9F 14 01 00 9F 23 01 00 9F 13 02 00 00
```

This response contains TLV data objects (without spaces). I have converted the response as described in the following:

```
// Read Record 1 with SFI2
//---------------------------------SEND READ RECORD-------------------
inCtlsSendVAPDU(0x2C,0x03,(unsigned char *)"\x00\xB2\x01\x14\x00",5);
clrscr();

inRet = inCTLSRecv2(Response, 269);
LOG_HEX_PRINTF("Essai EMV4 Read record 1 EMV Paypass:",Response,inRet);


if(Response[14]==0x70)
{
    sprintf(Response_PPSE,"%02X%02X",Response[12],Response[13]);//To retrieve  length of received data 
    t1=hexToInt(Response_PPSE);// Convert length to integer
    t11=t1-2;
    i=14; 
    k=0;

    //--------------------------- Converting data to be used later---------
    while(i<t11+14)// 14 to escape  the header+ command+ status+ length 
    {
        sprintf(READ1+(2*k),"%02X",Response[i]);
        i++;
        k++;
    }
```

Now I should check if this Response contains the Mandatory Tags:

- 5A   - Application Primary Account Number (PAN)
- 5F24 - Application Expiration Date
- 8C   - Card Risk Management Data Object List 1 (CDOL1)
- 8D   - Card Risk Management Data Object List 2 (CDOL2)

So I tried the following to check for the 5A tag (Application Primary Account Number (PAN)):

```
i=0;
t11=2*t11;

while(i<=t11)
{
    strncpy(Response_PPSE,READ1+i,2);

    if(strncmp(Response_PPSE,"\x05\x0A")==0)
    {
        write_at("true",4,1,1);// Just to test on the terminal display 
        goto end;
    }
    else 
        i=i+2;
}  
goto end;
```

I don't know why nothing is displayed on the terminal, The if block is not executed!

I  tried to print the `5A` tag manually by:

```
strncpy(Response_PPSE,READ1+44,2);
write_at(Response_PPSE,strlen(Response_PPSE),1,1);
```

And it display the right value!!

Can someone helps to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't find that tag because you are not searching for the string "5A" but for the string "\x05\x0A" (ENQ character + line feed character). Moreover, I wonder if the above code actually compiles as you did not specify the mandatory length argument to `strncmp()`. You could try something like

```
if(strncmp(Response_PPSE,"5A", 2)==0)
```

instead.

However, you should understand that you are scanning the whole response data for the value `5A`. Therefore, finding this value could also mean that it was part of some other TLV tag's *data* field, *length* field or even part of a multi-byte *tag* field. It would therefore make sense to implement (or use an existing) TLV parser for the BER (Basic Encoding Rules) format.

Comment: Can you give me some ideas about existing TLV Parser using C language ? @Michael Roland

Comment: @SaraSara No, I can't.

Comment: I'm new here so i don't know all forum rules, Thanks you for mentioning It @Michael Roland

Comment: Btw;Thanks for your help @ Michael

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good approach to search a specific byte in a raw byte-stream data using strings functions at first place.

The generic TLV parser is a very easy algorithm and you will do it in 30 minutes or so.

In general a pseudo-code for TLV parser that look for a specific Tag would be something like this:

```
index = 0
while (byte[i] != 0x5A or EOF)
{
     length = DecodeLength(byte[i+1])
     i += length + 2 // + 1 for L (length) byte itself, it might be encoded with
                     // 2 bytes so the function DecodeLength can return the number 
                     // of bytes lenght has been encoded
                     // +1 for T (tag) byte
}

if(EOF) return tag_not_found

return byte[i + 2], length // pointer to data for Tag '5A'and length of data
```